# Doesn't work request Google Developer API (anomalies)

Tags: google-api, google-developers-console

I'm sending a request to the API following [the documentation format](https://developers.google.com/play/developer/reporting/reference/rest/v1beta1/anomalies/list).

```
from google.auth.transport.requests import AuthorizedSession
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from datetime import date, timedelta, datetime


# Путь к файлу JSON с учетными данными
credentials_file = '.json'

# Скоупы доступа к API
scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/playdeveloperreporting']

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    credentials_file, scopes=scopes)

authed_session = AuthorizedSession(credentials)

app = my_app_id
url = f'https://playdeveloperreporting.googleapis.com/v1beta1/apps/{app}/anomalies'

resp = authed_session.get(url)
print(resp.status_code)
print(resp.text)
```

However, I'm receiving an error.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?"

tried different app id and link for test request
`GET https://playdeveloperreporting.googleapis.com/v1beta1/apps/com.example.app/anomalies`